# Cursor leak on Google Play Services

Tags: google-play-services

I've been trying to track a cursor leak on my code and this is the only thing that strict mode is giving me. Anyone have any idea what piece of Google Play Services is causing it?

Thanks.

```
E/StrictMode: Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed. database = /data/user/0/mypackage/databases/google_app_measurement_local.db, table = null, query = select count(1) from messages
`android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did` not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.<init>(SQLiteCursor.java:98)
at
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:50)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1318)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1257)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzatv.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzatv.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaul.zzc(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzauj.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzauj.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzauj$8.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaud$zzd.run(Unknown Source)
```