# Getting errors unrelated to the project in Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, sqliteopenhelper

I am trying to setup Google Cloud Messaging but I get SQLiteDatabase error even if am not using SQLIteDatabase in the project.

Comment: Please add more details like code used and the exact error that appears in the logs. Share what you have tried. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: please check @casolorz question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44357062/cursor-leak-on-google-play-services)
It's the same as the problem I have